# What does the ":" mean in Search(name, onlyActive: true)?

Tags: c#, syntax, parameters, arguments

I've got this method, which I don't understand.. I tried searching for it but since I didn't really know what to search for I didn't find anything.

Can somebody please explain it to me?

```
    public List<listElementType> Search(string name,
    bool onlyActive = true,
    bool onlyDeleted = true,
    decimal from = 0,
    decimal to = decimal.MaxValue)
    {
    // Some SQL stuff
    return ...;
    }
```

And why can I use it like I mentioned in the title?

```
    Search(name, onlyActive: true);
```

Comment: that is setting the value of a parameter via its name instead of its position

Comment: You are searching for "named and optional arguments": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [named argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx), it's calling the method `Search` with `name = name` and `onlyActive = true`.

It's actually doing the exact same thing as calling

```
Search(name);
```

You can use them on methods to specify the argument you want to change, effectively allowing us to skip default arguments. For example:

```
Search(name, from: 1, to: 2);
```

Comment: Actually you can use them also if the method defines no default values. They are not as useful, but e.g. on some occasions they can make the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Search(name, onlyActive: true);
```

This is the syntax to use named parameters, since this function has default parameters you can use this type of syntax to only specify the ones you want to -- the rest will be the default.

Answer (score 0):

These are called **named arguments.**

msdn link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd264739.aspx

Basically, instead of just putting the arguments down in the usual order, you can put their names, followed by a colon, and the value. This is EXTREMELY useful for functions like this:

```
Func(string a = "", string b = "")
{
//blah
}
```

when you only want to set b. Without them, you'd need to do `Func("", "somecustomvalue");` Now, you can just go `Func(b: "somecustomvalue");`